# I receive conversion varchar to float error when insert **set rowcount=1** in first line of code

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I receive an error

> Coversion of varchar to float

when I write

```
set rowcount = 1
```

on first line of my code.

My script is:

```
select   
    vh.VchNum, ct.Val, r.RoutSheetNo, vi.FinalQty,
rh.RequestNo, vh.VchDate,
p.PartCode, d.Title, co.val  
from
    inv.InvVchHdr vh
join 
    acc.DL d on d.AccNum = vh.DLREF
join 
    inv.InvVchItm vi on vi.VchHdrRef = vh.VchHdrID
join 
     inv.InvVchItmCtrl ct on ct.VchItmRef = vi.VchItmID
join 
     QCS.QcsCertificateOfAnalysis q on q.Number = ct.Val
join 
     USR.kalaf_info_p kp on kp.Id = q.QcsCertificateOfAnalysisId
join 
     USR.coil_trace co on co.id = kp.coil_id
join 
     inv.Part p on p.Serial = vi.PartRef
join 
     inv.InvRqstItm rq on rq.RqstItmID = vi.RefNum
join 
     inv.InvRqstHdr rh on rh.RqstHdrID = rq.HdrRef
join 
     PRD.vwPrdOrderItemPlan pl on rh.OrdPlnBase = pl.OrdPlnId
join 
     prd.prdroutsheet r on r.OrdPlnRef = pl.OrdPlnId
where 
     pl.pPartRef not in (select pipe_code from usr.pipe_kalaf) 
     and pl.pPartRef not in (select Serial from inv.Part where PartName like '%لاف%') 
     and vi.VchType = 57

union

    select vh.VchNum,ct.Val,pl.OrdPlnNo
    ,vi.FinalQty,
    rh.RequestNo,vh.VchDate,
    p.PartCode,d.Title,co.val  from
    inv.InvVchHdr vh
    join acc.DL d
    on d.AccNum=vh.DLREF
    join 
    inv.InvVchItm vi
    on vi.VchHdrRef=vh.VchHdrID
    join inv.InvVchItmCtrl ct
    on ct.VchItmRef=vi.VchItmID
    join QCS.QcsCertificateOfAnalysis q
    on q.Number=ct.Val
    join USR.kalaf_info_p kp
    on kp.Id=q.QcsCertificateOfAnalysisId
    join USR.coil_trace co
    on co.id=kp.coil_id
    join 
    inv.Part p
    on p.Serial=vi.PartRef
    join inv.InvRqstItm rq
    on rq.RqstItmID=vi.RefNum
    join inv.InvRqstHdr rh
    on rh.RqstHdrID=rq.HdrRef
    join PRD.vwPrdOrderItemPlan pl
    on rh.OrdPlnBase=pl.OrdPlnId
    where pl.pPartRef in (select pipe_code from usr.pipe_kalaf) and vi.VchType=57

    SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

i use sql server 2000 and when I remove setrowcount statement, problem resolve.
please help me

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution by yourself.

Comment: my application insert **set rowcount =1** in first line of my code and this script used for crytal report program.i want to find reason of convertion error.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the =(equal) sign**

from

```
set rowcount = 1
```

To

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
```